# Proxy class for accessing other class' items as attributes (__getitem__ infinite recursion)

Tags: python, proxy-classes

I have a class `LabelMapper` (a `boost::python` class), which implements the dictionary protocol. I would like to have a proxy class which will use attributes for accessing that dicionary. I've seen many posts for overriding `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` but I can't seem to get it right.

The naive approach (below) leads to infinite recursion due to `self.mapper` invoking `LabelMapperProxy.__getattr__`, which in turn needs `self.mapper` and so on.

```
class LabelMapper(object):
   def __init__(self): self.map={}
   def __getitem__(self,key): return self.map[key]
   def __setitem__(self,key,val): self.map[key]=val
   def __delitem__(self,key): del self.map[key]

class LabelMapperProxy(object):
   def __init__(self,mapper): self.mapper=mapper
   def __getattr__(self,key): return self.mapper[key]
   def __setattr__(self,key,val): self.mapper[key]=val
   def __delattr__(self,key): del self.mapper[key]

lm=LabelMapper()
lm['foo']=123

# construct the proxy
lmp=LabelMapperProxy(mapper=lm)
print lmp.foo                    # !!! recursion
lmp.bar=456
print lmp.bar,lm['bar']
```

What is the solution? Perhaps is there such a proxy pre-cooked in the standard library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to *set* a new attribute on your `Proxy` instance:

```
class LabelMapperProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, mapper): self.mapper = mapper
```

This triggers a `__setattr__`, which tries to access the non-existent `self.mapper` attribute, so `__getattr__` is consulted (which is called for all missing attributes). And `__getattr__` tries to access `self.mapper`....

The solution is to set `mapper` directly in `self.__dict__`:

```
class LabelMapperProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, mapper): self.__dict__['mapper'] = mapper
```

Alternatively, use the original baseclass `__setattr__` just for the `mapper` attribute:

```
class LabelMapperProxy(object):
   def __init__(self, mapper): self.mapper = mapper

   def __setattr__(self, key, val):
       if key == 'mapper':
           return super(LabelMapperProxy, self).__setattr__(key, val)
       self.mapper[key] = val
```

Comment: Just my 2c: I'd rename `mapper` into something like `__mapper` so that if somebody wants to use `mapper` as an attribute name it will remain consistent.

Comment: @bereal: sure, but that would not have solved the problem at hand here. :-)

Comment: Great! How come `__getattr__` does not get in loop when `self.mapper` is looked up in `__getattr__`? Is that the `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` difference?

Comment: @eudoxos: Exactly; `__getattr__` is only called if the attribute has not been found elsewhere first.

Comment: @bereal: if you use `__mapper` (with two leading underscores), it actually breaks, since python will mange that name when looking it up.

Comment: @eudoxos: There are ways around that, but that does complicate things.

Comment: @eudoxos: Anything else I need to add to my answer? Was it helpful in any way?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: "Since there is no `.mapper` attribute yet, that triggers a `__setattr__`" Should it be different if there was a `.mapper` attribute already? The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) and my test on Python 3.4 show that even if `object.attribute` exist, `object.__setattr__` will be invoked. "Note that if the attribute is found through the normal mechanism, __getattr__() is not called. (This is an intentional asymmetry between __getattr__() and __setattr__().)"

Comment: @Jérôme: the sentence is indeed a little confusing, sorry. I mention that the attribute is not there jet because `__setattr__` then triggers `__getattr__`; it is the latter step where this matters. I'll see about improving it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the trap:

```
class LabelMapperProxy(object):
   def __init__(self, mapper):
       # This will not assign this object's attribute 
       # since __setattr__ is overriden.
       # Instead, it will do self.mapper['mapper'] = mapper
       self.mapper=mapper

   def __getattr__(self, key): 
       # And this won't find `self.mapper` and resort to __getattr__
       # (which is itself)
       return self.mapper[key]  

   def __setattr__(self, key, val): 
       self.mapper[key]=val

   def __delattr__(self, key): 
       del self.mapper[key]
```